# Cordova plugin-locktask

Tags: java, android, cordova, plugins, android-screen-pinning

I am working on a cordova project and I want to use the plugin locktask provided by cordova itself to pin an android app. I could use other plugins successfully but this plugin does not work for some reason.

Another solution could be implementing the startlocktask() method using the native java class but I still didn't know how to invoke this method into the javascript code

After addding the cordova plugin using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-locktask` a plugin file is downloaded. 
However, when I use this line in the javascript, it deosn't work
`window.plugins.locktask.startLockTask();`

P.S. there is a java function StartLockTask() that would solve the problem but I do not know how to invoke a java function inside the javascript code

Comment: Post the code which is not working

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer for this is to add the plugin cordova-plugin-locktask and use the method LockTask.startLockTask(); in the JavaScript